# HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost,timeoutIntervalForRequest not affecting with defaultSession when used in iOS custom protocol

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am using custom protocol where I create NSURLSession with defaultConfiguration. Here is my code -

```
`   
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10.0;
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10.0;
config.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 2;
config.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyToUse;

[NSURLProtocol setProperty:@YES forKey:@"MyURLProtocolHandledKey" inRequest:mReq];

if(!_mySession) {
    _mySession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                              delegate:self
                         delegateQueue:nil];
}
```

`

When App is making hundreds of request, there is gradual increase in response time in serving requests from custom protocol. I can see maximum timeout of 60sec. There is no effect of these configuration parameters.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to say, but... are you sure these requests aren't all going into separate sessions?  Also, bear in mind that a gradual increase in response time is exactly what you'd expect if you're limiting yourself to two active connections at a time.  The other requests will queue up waiting for a chance to get sent.

Answer (score 0):

Some `URLSessionConfiguration` properties should be set up before configuration is used to create a new `URLSession`. For example to set up a `timeoutIntervalForRequest` you have to do the following:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 2
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
```